# GetChildAtPoint returning null when there is something there

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently writing a C# program that dynamically creates a form from an xml. The current xml contains 67 strings that I need. However when the for loop reaches 34 or 35 it returns null. Code is below

```
for(int x =0; x < 67: x++){
CheckBox sue = (CheckBox)GetChildAtPoint(new Point(760, loc));
loc = loc + 20;
          }
```

I've checked the form manually and there is something there and I'm using the most up to date framework. I'm also posting the code used to dynamically post the checkboxes and labels.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < cnt; x++)
        {

            /*creating the form*/
            String edit = "e1";
            String template = "t1";
            this.Controls.Add(new Label() {Text = data[x], Width=540,     Name = x.ToString(), Location = new Point(20, loc) });
            this.Controls.Add(new CheckBox() {Checked = true, Width = 20, Name = edit, Location = new Point(560, loc) });
            this.Controls.Add(new CheckBox(){ Width = 20, Name = template, Location = new Point(760, loc)});


            loc = loc + 20; 


        }
```

The only thing that sounds logically to me is that there is a limit to GetChildAtPoint and the xml format is a standard site.xml file for enterprise sites. Anyway to complete this will help me greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, GetChildAtPoint only works for the visible area.  Pretty much meant to be used with the Mouse location.

I think you would have to consider another method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 67; ++i) {
  foreach (CheckBox c in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) {
    if (c.Bounds.Contains(new Point(0, loc))) {
      // do something
    }
  }
  loc += 20;
}
```

You might want to consider setting the height of the controls as 20 pixels can cause overlap.

Another way is to check the name of the control:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 67; ++i) {
  string checkName = "CheckBox" + i.ToString();
  if (this.Controls.ContainsKey(checkName)) {
    CheckBox checkBox = this.Controls[checkName] as CheckBox;
  }
}
```

Which you would have to add to your builder:

```
this.Controls.Add(new CheckBox() { Name = "CheckBox" + i.ToString(), etc...
```

Comment: I've thought about naming them individually but I believe it won't help since it's these controls are dynamic. 67 is just one site which another one could be 10 or 32. It depends on the site.xml.

Comment: I'm going to try this(in a few hours)... I'll let you know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that cnt >= 67

That's an unusual way of enumerating controls, wouldn't it be easier just to look up the control by name?

e.g set the the Name to "CheckBoxAtLocx" and then use `Controls["CheckBoxAtLocx"]`?

Other ways I'd consider doing this would be to add All the controls to a list when creating them.

So the line

```
this.Controls.Add(new CheckBox(){ Width = 20, Name = template, Location = new Point(760, loc)});
```

becomes

```
var TempCheckbox = new CheckBox(){ Width = 20, Name = template, Location = new Point(760, loc)}
MyCheckboxList.Add(TempCheckbox); //Keep a reference for later
this.Controls.Add(TempCheckbox);
```

Or I'd use the tag property and store additional information such as an Identifier